# How can I force IIS7 to log the actual default document of a directory rather than a "/"?

Tags: iis, iis-7, logging, log-files, default-document

Logging under IIS7 seems to have changed in that access to a parent directory with a default document is now logged differently than IIS6.

The *s-uri-stem* field appears to ignore whatever documents have been defined in the Default Documents module. According to Microsoft this is by design.

- Under **IIS6**, if you were to go to "example.com", the log would show "**GET /default.htm - 80**".
- Under **IIS7**, if you were to go to "example.com", the log file would show "**GET / - 80**".

For web analytics purposes, we need IIS7 to log access to a parent directory with a default document to log it like IIS6 above.

How can we do that without using URL Rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your best option is to use the IIS URL Rewrite module.  Something like this:

```
<rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/default.htm" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Another possible solution (I know, this seems a little hack), is to create a different default document page (index.htm for example) and then have a meta refresh tag in the content of that page to send the request to default.htm

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/default.htm">
```

Other than those options, you might have to write some code to perform the redirect.